# r check if string contains special characters

Tags: r, string, grepl

I am checking if a string contains any special characters. This is what I have, and it's not working,

```r
if(grepl('^\\[:punct:]', val))
```

So if anybody can tell me what I am missing, that will be helpful.

### Special characters

```
~ ` ! @# $ % ^ & * | : ; , ." |
```

Comment: @RichardScriven, ha , all characters like ~ ` ! @# $ % ^ & * | : ; , ." |

Comment: `grepl('[^[:punct:]]', val)` is the appropriate incantation of what you were attempting I believe.

Comment: @thelatemail and Rich that worked.

Answer (score 5):

As @thelatemail pointed out in the comments you can use:

```
grepl('[^[:punct:]]', val)
```

which will result in `TRUE` or `FALSE` for each value in your vector. You can add `sum()` to the beginning of the statement to get the total number of these cases.

You can also use:

```
grepl('[^[:alnum:]]', val)
```

which will check for any value that is not a letter or a number.